# Can I create SQLite table and insert values at the same time?

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to create an `SQLite` table and insert value at the same time. Can I do something like this? For example,

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_SOMETHING = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(element1 123, element2 888, element3 435); 
//element1 = 123
//element2 = 888
//element1 = 435
```

Or, I have to do `CREATE` and `INSERT` separately? 
Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK the create and insert statements would have to be separate.  _However_, you could execute both within a single transaction, such that logically the two of them would occur as a single event.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TABLE ... AS ...` allows a query.
The first row should use SELECT in order to be able to specify column names:

```
CREATE TABLE t AS
SELECT 123 AS element1, 888 AS element2, 435 AS element3
UNION ALL
VALUES (234, 999, 546),
       (345, NULL, 657);
```